# Android - XMPP with Openfire

Tags: java, android, networking, protocols

I'm programming a network multi-player game and I decided to use XMPP for communication over the internet - since it should be quite good and didn't find any other better alternative.

I wish to use openfire XMPP server - if you know something better, please let me know. So I want to implement the Openfire plugin, which would accept all client messages and do something with them:

1. Forward messages to destined client.
2. Grab something from the database and return the data to the original client (like player list).

What I need in the game:

1. Getting a player list. I can achieve this with the UserManager#getUsers() from Openfire.
2. Storing the player details on the server: the player name, points, life, group to which the player belong. I don't know if I can define a simple java class within openfire, so that it would automatically save it to the database - I would also need to provide the database functions to store the data into mysql by hand.
3. Sending a message to an offline user, so that it waits there until the user logins - then sends the message to the user, informing it that some other player is challenging it to a game.

Is there any better way of doing that? If not, can Openfire do what I described?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , this thing can be done by openfire ,

and  if you want to use another opensource server , you can find it from here http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

Answer (score 1):

In the server sided, you can use Openfire, in the client side you can use [SMACK](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/).
Probably you should look at other protocols, if this will need to develop custom messages within XMPP.